# How to find the upto the last li element using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following html content....

I need to search only the `li`(s) text within an `ul` element

For example,

```
$("#ul_first").find(li).each(function(index,value)
{
    alert(index)
});
```

The problem here is that find method finds `li` in the `#ul_second` element. I only want it to find `li` elements within a certain `ul` element and not child `ul` elements.

```
<ul id="ul_first">
     <li>a</li>
     <li>b</li>
     <li>c</li>
     <li>d</li>
     <li>c
             <ul id="ul_second">
                               <li>a</li>
                               <li>b</li>
                               <li>c</li>
                               <li>d</li>
             </ul>    
     </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the child selector. `>` will select ONLY direct children. Using find is like ommiting the `>` which will choose ALL descendants.

```
$("#ul_first > li").each(function(index,value) { alert(index) });
```

Comment: thanks mike, I have to wait 6 more minutes before accepting this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

you can try like below... it will help you

Fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/119/

```
Traversing/children

$('#ul_first').children('li').each(function(index,value) 
{     
 alert(index); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried using `$("#ul_first > li")$? This should find li elements that are directly below ul_first

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector to `'#ul_first > li'`. This checks for all li's that are a child of #ul_first.

The child selector, `>`, matches when the next selector is a direct child of it's parent.

**Source:** http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors